# Body Tag CSS styling respected by Chrome but not FireFox or IE

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having an issue when developing a WordPress theme. I developed the theme using Chrome, and everything looked fine. The theme is based on the Roots theme for WordPress:
http://www.rootstheme.com/

When I went to test the theme in IE and Firefox, none of the CSS elements that I defined in the `/css/style.css` file were being applied to the elements!

The site is http://precisionmfgmn.com/.

In Firebug, I am able to see the contents of the stylesheet in the HEAD section, but when I look at the HTML element, none of the rules in the sheet are being applied to the elements.

One notable example is the BODY element, which is not getting the background image applied to it.

Any ideas as to why this is happening in a browser-specific manner?

Comment: Have you looked at the body tag using chrome developer tool or firebug, it will show you what CSS file the body tag is taking effect.

Comment: The body element is taking rules from many of the other stylesheets in the theme, but not style.css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a mistake in your `.sidebar_bottom {margin-bottom: 30px;"}` declaration: that `"` double quotes are a mistake. Surely Chrome has a way to go on with it, but Firefox and IE ignore following rules.

A part, your rule in `style.css` that defines the background-image is applied to a `#body` and not to a `body` selector, so to an element with an `id` equal to `body` and not to the `body` element, which in your HTML code doesn't have any id.

It's a good policy to always check your CSS stylesheets with [the W3C validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) to avoid problems like the first one.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It was body before, but I added a # to it to see if that would help. I've since changed it back with no effect.

Comment: No problem :) Please, set the answer as the correct one to close the question.